# Why aren't some css properties appearing in my master page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a button on a non-master page that looks like this
[image: Login]

Now I have a master page and inside the content place holder I have a div tag, in which I write the contents of that specific page, the buttons inside that tag looks like this

[image]

Now they have the same css properties but they wont show up in the master page one, here is the code for the div tag and the buttons

```
.container-div 
{
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:8%;
    padding-left:10%;
    padding-right:10%;
    max-height:80%;
    z-index:0;
    font-family:Calibri;

}

#buttons {
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:20;
}

#buttons:hover {
    background-color:cadetblue;
}
```

and this is the html code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<div id="placeHolderDiv" class="container-div" runat="server">

    <asp:Button id="buttons" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="buttons" OnClick="cancel"/>


</div>
```

Comment: "this is the html code" — No, it isn't. That's ASP.NET code. The HTML is what gets sent to the browser. Look at the source code *in the browser*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change CSS classes from #buttons to .buttons
Because under master page generated ID will be not exactly buttons but there will be id prep-ended. you can check in source.

```
.buttons {
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:20;
}

.buttons:hover {
    background-color:cadetblue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some compilers are having hard time with parsing multiple elements with the same `id`, id should be uniques.

Change to "class=buttons" and the css selector to `.buttons{};`